# C#: Altering values for every item in an array

Tags: c#, linq, arrays, delegates, projection

I'm wondering if there is built-in .NET functionality to change each value in an array based on the result of a provided delegate.  For example, if I had an array `{1,2,3}` and a delegate that returns the square of each value, I would like to be able to run a method that takes the array and delegate, and returns `{1,4,9}`.  Does anything like this exist already?

Comment: Traditionally, that would be called Map; in Linq it's called Select.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Not that I'm aware of (replacing each element rather than converting to a new array or sequence), but it's incredibly easy to write:

```
public static void ConvertInPlace<T>(this IList<T> source, Func<T, T> projection)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        source[i] = projection(source[i]);
    }
}
```

Use:

```
int[] values = { 1, 2, 3 };
values.ConvertInPlace(x => x * x);
```

Of course if you don't really *need* to change the existing array, the other answers posted using `Select` would be more functional. Or the existing `ConvertAll` method from .NET 2:

```
int[] values = { 1, 2, 3 };
values = Array.ConvertAll(values, x => x * x);
```

This is all assuming a single-dimensional array. If you want to include rectangular arrays, it gets trickier, particularly if you want to avoid boxing.

Comment: +1 for ConvertAll which actually is what the OP asked for "method that takes the array and delegate, and returns..."

Comment: I don't get why this beats Nathan's answer for the accepted answer.  What am I missing?  Select does exactly what he needs, no?

Comment: @Richard: It's possible that Nathan's answer was as complete when my answer was accepted, in terms of the multi-dimensional support. The way I read the OP's question to start with, I thought he wanted to modify the array in place, which only my answer covers. For array to array conversion, `Array.ConvertAll` is more efficient and doesn't require .NET 3.5. If only a sequence is required, `Select` is fine as mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Please Correct me if I am wrong but i assume the ConvertInPlace method would be the best for performance since no new Array needs to be allocated, correct?

Comment: @J.Selchow: Assuming you want to modify the existing array, yes. (An overload accepting `T[] source` may be even faster, avoiding the `IList<T>` abstraction, but I wouldn't do that without measuring.)

Answer (score 43):

LINQ provides support for projections using the [Select](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb357126.aspx) extension method:

```
var numbers = new[] {1, 2, 3};
var squares = numbers.Select(i => i*i).ToArray();
```

You can also use the slightly less fluent [Array.ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx) method:

```
var squares = Array.ConvertAll(numbers, i => i*i);
```

Jagged arrays can be processed by nesting the projections:

```
var numbers = new[] {new[] {1, 2}, new[] {3, 4}};
var squares = numbers.Select(i => i.Select(j => j*j).ToArray()).ToArray();
```

Multidimensional arrays are a little more complex. I've written the following extension method which projects every element in a multidimensional array no matter what its rank.

```
static Array ConvertAll<TSource, TResult>(this Array source,
                                          Converter<TSource, TResult> projection)
{
    if (!typeof (TSource).IsAssignableFrom(source.GetType().GetElementType()))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    var dims = Enumerable.Range(0, source.Rank)
        .Select(dim => new {lower = source.GetLowerBound(dim),
                            upper = source.GetUpperBound(dim)});
    var result = Array.CreateInstance(typeof (TResult),
        dims.Select(dim => 1 + dim.upper - dim.lower).ToArray(),
        dims.Select(dim => dim.lower).ToArray());
    var indices = dims
        .Select(dim => Enumerable.Range(dim.lower, 1 + dim.upper - dim.lower))
        .Aggregate(
            (IEnumerable<IEnumerable<int>>) null,
            (total, current) => total != null
                ? total.SelectMany(
                    item => current,
                    (existing, item) => existing.Concat(new[] {item}))
                : current.Select(item => (IEnumerable<int>) new[] {item}))
        .Select(index => index.ToArray());
    foreach (var index in indices)
    {
        var value = (TSource) source.GetValue(index);
        result.SetValue(projection(value), index);
    }
    return result;
}
```

The above method can be tested with an array of rank 3 as follows:

```
var source = new int[2,3,4];

for (var i = source.GetLowerBound(0); i <= source.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    for (var j = source.GetLowerBound(1); j <= source.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
        for (var k = source.GetLowerBound(2); k <= source.GetUpperBound(2); k++)
            source[i, j, k] = i*100 + j*10 + k;

var result = (int[,,]) source.ConvertAll<int, int>(i => i*i);

for (var i = source.GetLowerBound(0); i <= source.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    for (var j = source.GetLowerBound(1); j <= source.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
        for (var k = source.GetLowerBound(2); k <= source.GetUpperBound(2); k++)
        {
            var value = source[i, j, k];
            Debug.Assert(result[i, j, k] == value*value);
        }
```

Comment: Your example should probably use a delegate rather than to specify the function in the lambda, to answer the question more specifically.

Comment: Very neat.  Will this take into account multi-dimensional arrays?

Comment: Ah there it is. I was looking for an Apply method or something. Never would have thought of it being named Select, but I suppose that goes along with the LINQ basis of all the fun extension methods.

Answer (score 7):

Using System.Linq you could do something like:

```
var newArray = arr.Select(x => myMethod(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

LINQ queries could easily solve this for you - make sure you're referencing System.Core.dll and have a

```
using System.Linq;
```

statement.  For example, if you had your array in a variable named numberArray, the following code would give you exactly what you're looking for:

```
 var squares = numberArray.Select(n => n * n).ToArray();
```

The final "ToArray" call is only needed if you actually need an array, and not an IEnumerable<int>.

Comment: Awesome, thanks.  Will this take into account multi-dimensional arrays?

Comment: No - for that, you'd want a nested select, like numberArrays.Select(as => as.Select(n => n * n).ToArray()).ToArray().  For an arguably more readable approach, just use two nested loops.

Answer (score 1):

you can use linq to accomplish this in shorthand but be careful remember that a foreach occurs underneath anyway.

```
int[] x =  {1,2,3};
x = x.Select(( Y ) => { return Y * Y; }).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution for M x N arrays, where M and N are not known at compile time.

```
    // credit: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq/
    public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> CartesianProduct<T>(IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> sequences)
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> result = new[] { Enumerable.Empty<T>() };
        foreach (var sequence in sequences)
        {
            // got a warning about different compiler behavior
            // accessing sequence in a closure
            var s = sequence;
            result = result.SelectMany(seq => s, (seq, item) => seq.Concat<T>(new[] { item }));
        }
        return result;
    }


    public static void ConvertInPlace(this Array array, Func<object, object> projection)
    {
        if (array == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        // build up the range for each dimension
        var dimensions = Enumerable.Range(0, array.Rank).Select(r => Enumerable.Range(0, array.GetLength(r)));

        // build up a list of all possible indices
        var indexes = EnumerableHelper.CartesianProduct(dimensions).ToArray();

        foreach (var index in indexes)
        {
            var currentIndex = index.ToArray();
            array.SetValue(projection(array.GetValue(currentIndex)), currentIndex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thats probably the best one I've found... and good that you gave the credit to the guy that wrote it (even though the guy that asked the question got pissed off he didnt apply it)