# How to add value to each item in array inline style

Tags: c#

Lets say I have an array

```
string[] arr = new string[] {"1","2","3"};
```

I would like to add a string to the end of value, something like this:

```
arr.appendToEnd(" Test");

return arr; // returns {"1 Test","2 Test","3 Test"}
```

I was wondering if there is something built-in that can do this, rather than having to build my own extension method.

Comment: just loop through the array and add to each element a space and test . i don't think there is a built in method.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867961/c-altering-values-for-every-item-in-an-array you could probably modify this to suit your needs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't anything built-in. You could use LINQ to create a *new* array easily:

```
arr = arr.Select(x => x + " Test").ToArray();
```

... but that's not going to modify the original array. If anything else has a reference to the original array, they won't see the change. Usually that's actually a good thing IMO, but occasionally you might want to modify the existing collection.

For that, you could write your own general purpose method to modify an existing array (or any other `IList<T>` implementation):

```
public static void ModifyAll<T>(this IList<T> source, Func<T, T> modification)
{
    // TODO: Argument validation
    for (int i = 0; i < source.Count; i++)
    {
        source[i] = modification(source[i]);
    }
}
```

Then you could use:

```
arr.ModifyAll(x => x + " Test");
```

I would definitely use this rather than writing a string-concatenation-specific extension method.

Comment: Hey, thanks. What is `arr` before you use `.ToArray()` ? (curious)

Comment: @RealWorld: I'm not sure what you mean. `arr.Select(x => x + " Test")` returns a lazily-evaluated iterator which will yield the result of the projection when asked. It doesn't modify `arr` at all.

Answer (score 0):

If by "built-in" you mean the function `appendToEnd` exists, then no.

However, its easy enough to do:

```
arr = arr.Select(s => s + " Test").ToArray();
```

Comment: That won't modify the array.

Comment: @JonSkeet Correct, fixed now.

Comment: That still doesn't do what the OP asked for, which is to modify the original array. The difference can be important. I've provided a sample in my answer.

Comment: @JonSkeet No question it will create a new array, which could certainly be important. +1 to your much more complete answer; I assumed the OP wanted a one-liner which is why I didn't suggest the loop.