# C# dynamic array from an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, dynamic

I have an array that is fetching filenames from an OpenFileDialog, so I have an unknown amount of items in this array.
I am trying to generate a readme file utilizing each of these items, but they need to include more details.
So for example purposes lets say I have this original array:

- file1.png
- file2.txt
- file3.jpg

I start off with this:

`string[] dependencies = listbox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();`

and then I want to count how many files I have in there, the number obviously being 3 from the example above:
`int count = dependencies.Count();`

I want the new array to show this text in my .txt file later:

```
App1 = file1.png
App2 = file2.txt
App3 = file3.jpg
```

In other words, I need to append text to the filenames from above and then store them as items of a new array. How would I go about this?
I stopped here:

```
string[] dependencies = listbox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
int count = dependencies.Count();

                string[] newarr = { "" };

                    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                   //help
                }
```

Comment: question: could you not use a `List<string>` instead of a `string[]` ? you can `.Add(...)` to a list (indeed, to must approximations, a `List<T>` is a "dynamic `T[]`");  just : `var dependencies = listbox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToList();` or `var newarr = new List<string>  { "" };` (depending on what you're trying to do)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add value to each item in array inline style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26263326/how-to-add-value-to-each-item-in-array-inline-style)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without Linq you'd use something like this:

```
// your first array:
string[] dependencies = listbox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();

// the desired second array with your beautiful name:
string[] newarr = new string[dependencies.Length];
for(int i = 0; i < dependencies.Length; i++)
{
    newarr[i] = $"App{i + 1} = {dependencies[i]}";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply do something like:

```
var strings = listbox1.Items.OfType<string>().Select((s, i) => $"App {i+1} {s}");
var singleString = string.Join( Environment.NewLine, strings);
```

This uses an LINQ overload of `Select` that creates an index for each item. Creates a new string from both the index and the file name, and finally merges all the strings, using a new line as the separator.

Note that "dynamic array" means a collection that can change size, in c# this is called `List<T>`, and while you could use a list, there is nothing in your example that require it.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ's `.Select()` might be helpful here. `.Select()` returns a new `IEnumerable<TResult>` for each item in the original `IEnumerable`, with whatever function you've given it applied. This function can take in the item in the IEnumerable, as well as its index.

Example:

```cs
string[] dependencies = listbox1.Items.OfType<string>().ToArray();
string[] formatted = dependencies.Select((s, i) => $"App{i} = {s}").ToArray();
```

Note that the index (`i`) starts at 0, you might want to use `i+1` in your specific case.

Answer (score 0):

You can *query* `listbox1.Items` with a help of *Linq* and get `string[] newarr` as a result of the query:

```
string[] newarr = listbox1
  .Items
  .OfType<string>()
  .Select((value, index) => $"App{index + 1} = {value}")
  .ToArray();
```