# Appending a Char to each element in a array

Tags: c#, vb.net

Input in my case is a string with a list of elements separated by Comma

Input:

```
var input = "123,456,789";
```

Expected Output (a string):

```
"'123','456','789'"
```

I'm looking for a solution in VB.net but i'm not so familiar with it. So, I tried it in c#. Not sure what i'm missing.

My Attempt:

```
var input = "123,456,789";
var temp = input.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
Array.ForEach(temp, a => a = "'" + a + "'");
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",temp));
```

Actual Output:

```
"123,456,789"
```

Any help in funding a solution in vb.net is much appreciated :)

Comment: Any help in funding a solution in vb.net is much appreciated :)

Comment: Your `ForEach` is not doing what you think it's doing (it's updating a local variable `a`, not the values in the array).

Comment: because of the way strings work, when you do `a = "'" + a + "'"`, you are not replacing the value of the a.  You are not changing the value of the items in the collection of strings returned by the split.  You **are** creating a new string and naming it a.  That leaves the items in the `temp` collection unchanged.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use LINQ:

```
var result = string.Join(",", input.Split(',').Select(x => "'" + x + "'"))
```

This splits the string at the `,` delimiter, then adds the quotes around the pieces using  `Select()`, and then reassembles the array using `string.Join()`

**Edit**: Here is the equivalent VB.NET solution:

```
Dim result As String
result = String.Join(",", input.Split(",").Select(Function (x) ("'" & x & "'" )))
```

Comment: This works perfect in c#. I was actually looking for a VB.net solution. Few of these functions are not available in Vb.net :(

Comment: @Reddy If you wanted a vb.net solution you should have tagged it with vb.net only and not c# and shown your attempt at doing it in vb.net.

Comment: I tagged it both c# and vb but looks like someone edited it. As I was unable to accomplish this in C# i didn't try in vb.net at the time of posting this question.

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/MLZCQ9

It is complaining about "'Select' is not a member of 'System.Array'."

Comment: @Reddy You have to add `Imports System.Linq`

Comment: How can i forget that... Thanks for your time (Y)

Comment: why did you remove the  .toArray()  ?

Comment: I like this way. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`input = Regex.Replace(input, "\d+", "'$0'");`

Answer (score 0):

```
var input = "123,456,789";
var temp = input.Split(new Char[] { ',' });
temp = Array.ConvertAll(temp, a => a = "'" + a + "'");

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", temp));
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3867998/194717

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot of solutions here but, I think, this will mach more faster:

```
var newStr = "'" + string.Replace(str, ",", "','") + "'";
```

in VB.NET

```
Private newStr = "'" & String.Replace(str, ",", "','") & "'"
```